# Why is it always women and not men in: “Soccer mom,” “Tiger mom,” “Helicopter mom,” “Wal-Mart mom,” and “Security mom”?

Tags: american-english, word-usage, neologisms

In connection with my question about the meaning and currency of “Security mom,” I was drawn to the fact that all the following labels; “Soccer mom,” “Wal-Mart mom,” “Security mom” are combined with *mom* and not *dad*, although education, consumption, security are common interest for both women and men.

In Japan, we have 主夫 -  housekeeping husband. We say 教育ママ、教育パパ- child- education-obssesed mama, papa, and 育児ママ、育児パパ-nursing mama, papa.

Are there any linguistic, cultural or any thinkable factors to suffix “mom” to common or mutual social concerns such as education, politics, occupation, finance, consumption, and lifestyle?

Comment: Because the respective men are literal, not idiomatic :)

Comment: I don't know about Japan, but here in the US, in houses where one parent has a full-time job and the other does not, then it is most often the woman (Mom) who has charge of the children and their extracurricular activities, and who is more actively engaged in their managing their day-to-day lives (including petitioning on their behalf, of politicians, school boards, PTAs, etc). In other words; these women *define themselves* by being a "Mom", as the father might define himself by being a salesman or banker or coach or whatever.

Comment: The  expression 'tiger mom' was actually  coined in Asia (Cina - south-est Asia) rather than in US.  Origin - 

coined by Amy Chua in the book Battle Hymn of the Tiger Mother (2011).

Comment: It seems that in certain areas (e.g., playgroups), it is very hard for men to get in because they are almost exclusively attended by mothers and their children. However, fathers do often get involved way too seriously with the sports and/or hobbies of their children. Not sure if there is a name for that.

Comment: @dan et al., That's sociology. English is not responsible for it, let alone AmE.

Comment: Not just 'superwomen' in US, but also ordinary ones as Laura Bush officialy declared: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-347045/Laura-Bush-Im-Desperate-Housewife.html :))

Comment: @Kris, not sure I take your point? *Soccer mom* et al are labels for social phenomena, for which there are no (disclaimers: *essentially*, *yet*, etc) corresponding categories for men. Yochi is asking why we have female labels but not male labels. So surely explaining their origins (which necessarily entails describing the imbalances) is simply proper etymology, relevant to the question and appropriate for the site?

Comment: @dan etymology is fine. Sociolinguistics takes care of the finer details.

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180899/soccer-mom-why-soccer/180910#180910

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about politics and stereotypes in America, not English language.

Comment: @medica ... let's call it sociolinguistics.

Comment: Yoichi, as a native speaker, I don't hear the same things. 'soccer-mom' is a very popular expression, mad up and popularized during a presidential election (Bsuh vs Gore?). 'Tiger mom' I only heard of from the title of a recent book which I think coined the term. I've only ever heard 'helicopter _parents_'.  Your other two I've never heard of. So I disagree that there is evidence here of gender stereotyping (except possibly the popularity of the first two might be evidence). Whatever gender stereotyping there might be in English/Anglo culture (a lot!), I see no 'X-mom' trend here.

Comment: @Mitch - if it's not evidence of *gender stereotyping*, why do we *not* see *soccer dads*, *security dads* (from Joe Biden), etc (even in decreased frequency)? I'm not sure this is socio*linguistics* as much as *sociology*. Anyway, women are no more single-issue voters than men.

Comment: @Josh61 Please note, Amy Chua is an American (of Asian descent) and her book was written and published in English.

Comment: @ChrisSunami - Yes I know..but for business reasons I have been travelling in Cina and SE Asia since early 90's where the expression became popular at least 10/15 years ago. I think Amy Chua just put down in writing an already existing expression in those place.

Comment: @medica Sorry, I was being too subtle. I meant I don't see a gender stereotyping trend in 'X-mom', because I've only seen two of the examples Yoichi gave. But, yes, there is great evidence of gender stereotyping in those _individual_ terms. But now that I think of it, the '-mom' add-in is pretty productive in AmE (hockey-mom, little-league mom, mom-pants, um I'm sure there are others). So Even though I don't agree with Yoichi's examples, I think he's right that there is a pattern with '-mom'. But I don't don't think that makes English and anglo culture any more sexist than other languages.

Comment: On the other hand, you almost never hear the expression "deadbeat mom," so dads still get a special shout-out in at least one regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are *moms* being targeted? Because, as Robusto said, they are an important demographic.

In every election since 1964, female voters have outnumbered male voters. Even though the population of adults eligible for voting is 50% male and 50% female, [*women vote significantly more often than men*](http://www.cawp.rutgers.edu/fast_facts/voters/documents/genderdiff.pdf). In the 2000 election, women's votes carried 18 of the [*battleground states*](http://www.cawp.rutgers.edu/fast_facts/voters/documents/Battleground2000.pdf).

Therefore the thinking is that the women most likely to vote are the demographic most likely to influence the election. *Security dads* are a smaller and less important demographis than *security moms*.

It also must be noted that it is seen as less threatening to label the (voting, as well as other) behaviors of *women* than *men*. The stereotype here is that women are **single issue voters** while men are not.

Answer (score 1):

Yoichi-san, the moms in question represent a voting or purchasing demographic, a subset of women's influence in America. It is not a literal expression but a figurative one. Advertisers, politicians running for office, pundits bloviating about them, all refer to them by various modifiers as a way to define them for exploitation: mainly, how to win their votes or sell them something. Some women may accept such classification willingly or enthusiastically after the fact, but the categories don't exist until some of the above-mentioned groups create the definition artificially.

It is analogous to Richard Nixon calling his likely voters "the silent majority" in an attempt to position his policies as appealing to those who were not agitating for change: a marketing concept, nothing more.

Comment: Ok, but this avoids (or begs) the question. Why create classifications for *moms* but not *dads*? Why target women and not men? What do these women have in common with each other that they do not share with their male counterparts (to whom they are actually married)?

Comment: (Also, it's worth pointing out that the term *soccer mom* may have been adopted and promulgated by commercial and political groups, but it certainly wasn't *coined* by those groups; it was coined on the ground, in suburban America, as a heuristic.)

Comment: @DanBron: Because that is how the groups described above parse the American woman for their own purposes. You may not realize it, but women are the group most sought after by marketers, and attempts to categorize them are thus brought to the forefront in a way their parsings of men are not.

Comment: Robusto, I understood your answer; what I was asking for was a *rationale* for this parsing. In other words, Yochi asked for a *why*, not a *what*. To be clear, I, personally, *do* realize moms are specifically parsed out and sought after by commercial/political interests. I am even of the opinion that I know the reason. What I am saying here, however, is that that reason (or a different one, or several different ones) is not evident in your answer: in other words, your answer doesn't respond to the question (it merely brushes it aside, or re-asks it in different words).

Comment: I'm not American, but I'm curious about one thing. If "moms" are the most sought after demographic groups for marketers, advertisers, politicians etc. Why do some of these terms carry negative collocations?  I'd hardly think a *Walmart mom* is a flattering or winning slogan. They all seem slightly derogatory to me. I have a feeling that they are primarily slogans which have been tagged onto mothers by newspapers and journalists.

Comment: To my way of thinking, the *why* is implicit in the *what*. You obviously disagree. But to state it more baldly, the reason women are categorized in this manner is that the various groups mentioned want to have an easy handle for them, especially one that will resonate with the media and, even, with women themselves.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Because all labels become, essentially, two-edged swords. For example, the term "redneck" is viewed mainly as derogatory, but many Southerners embrace it as a badge of honor.

Comment: Robusto, again, we seem to be missing each other. You say "the various groups mentioned want an easy handle on *them*"; Yochi's specific question is *why **them***? Why do marketers etc want a handle on *soccer moms* instead of *soccer dads*? Why is it always *X mom* and never *X Dad*?

Comment: But isn't that to do with *reappropriation*, reclaiming the derogatory word for yourself. Like, homosexuals did with the terms *gay* and *queer*.

Comment: That is one of the concepts you could use to describe the process, but not the only one. Labels may be self-applied without ever being perceived as derogatory by a particular group.

Comment: @Mari-Lou, that's an interesting and deep question. Unfortunately I don't have the space or charter to answer you here. Is there a sociology.SE? BTW, it's worth reading the Wikipedia entry for *soccer mom*, which gets into some of the connotations/glosses of the term, as well as its origins (which is actually not journalism or politics, but an actual group of soccer moms in the 1960s). The political uptake and application of the word is actually an example of *appropriation*, as opposed to *re-appropriation* by the moms themselves.

Comment: What is pejorative in these -mom labels is the stereotype that @medica hit upon with "single-issue voter": there is an implied narrowness of focus or interest or behavior, almost a kind of tunnel vision, or some narrow range of predictable behaviors bordering on monomania.  When you get broadsided by a soccer mom (I'm speaking with faux chauvinism here) it's because she was so intent on getting those kids to practice on time that she was oblivious to all else.

Answer (score 1):

Because moms are (typically) the more active parent. They (more often) take children to and from soccer games, "hover" (helicopter) over their children. "Battle Cry of the Tiger Mother" was written (and performed) by Amy Chua, and not her husband (who was he?), etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Dan Bron implied, the reason is that descriptors like these are intended to indicate that the term is the primary identity for the person in the group.  A "soccer mom" is someone whose primary identity is that she is the mother of a soccer-playing child.

Whether or not it matches reality, it's widely believed that there is a substantial population of women whose primary identity is as a (particular kind of) parent of a (particular kind of) child, but that the population of men like this is much smaller.  You do occasionally hear terms like "soccer dad" or "stage dad" but they are rarer.

You might, for instance, identify Venus and Serena Williams' father as a "tennis dad," but there isn't the same sense that he represents a common demographic.