# Origin of Soccer

Tags: etymology, american-english, sports

What is called *football* in most of countries, called *soccer* in US. However, there are some inconsistent usage of these terms. For example, in Australia, they have *Football Federation Australia* (FFA) while they call the national team ***socceroos***.

My main question is what's origin of soccer? and the secondary one is why it's used instead of football? (I'm aware of American Football, too).

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked, did you look in the archives?

Comment: Apparently not, the closest one I found was: [“Football” and “Soccer”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355/football-and-soccer)

Comment: "soccer" is an alternative term in British English and was certainly used when I was growing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soccer, is an abbreviation of Association (of Football). U.S. Football later evolved from it with different rules:

***[Soccer](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=soccer&allowed_in_frame=0):***

> - 1889, socca, later socker (1891), soccer (1895), originally university slang (with jocular formation -er (3)), ***from a shortened form of Assoc., abbreviation of association in Football Association (as opposed to Rugby football)***; compare rugger. An unusual method of formation, but those who did it perhaps shied away from making a name out of the first three letters of Assoc.

***[Football](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=football&searchmode=none):***

> - Rules of the game first regularized at Cambridge, 1848; soccer (q.v.) split off in 1863. ***The U.S. style (known to some in England as "stop-start rugby with padding") evolved gradually 19c.***; the first true collegiate game is considered to have been played Nov. 6, 1869, between Princeton and Rutgers, at Rutgers, but the rules there were more like soccer. ***A rematch at Princeton Nov. 13, with the home team's rules, was true U.S. football. Both were described as foot-ball at Princeton.**+

Etymonline

Answer (score 2):

The English organization responsible for the sport is called the Football Association, so the sport became known as Association football, which may be abbreviated "Assoc. football."  Footballer would be a good term for somebody playing the game, except for the confusion with players of American football.  "Assoc + er" makes the distinction clear.  It's a short step to dropping the initial "A" that sounds like an article.